# I need some "known clique size graph" dataset for an experiment . Is there any open source or site, where I can find them?

Tags: graph, dataset, clique

I need some "known clique size graph" dataset for an experiment . Is there any open source or site, where I can find them ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I sadly don't know a source which provides that information.
You generally can get alot of graphs from [Network-Repository](http://networkrepository.com/index.php).
There you can see the maximum degree *m*, so the graph can only have a clique of size at most *m+1*.

You then can manually insert a clique of size *m+1* into the graph, and this clique then has to be at least as big as all other cliques.